# How to refresh local Storage without reload the page in javaScript or AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, refresh

How to refresh local Storage without reload the page in javaScript or AngularJS? 
Please show me a demo to resolve this issue.

I write a function in a Controller to update a value in localStorage and use this value directly in another Controller but this value wasn't update until i refresh the page.

I just want to know if it's able to refresh (not clear) all value in localStorage after update it without any refreshing action?

Comment: What issue? If you want to store a new value, overwrite or modify an existing one - then you just do that. No idea how that relates to reloading the page at all.

Comment: Provide your code which is you try but can't success.

Comment: always mention the scenario of your problem

Answer (score 0):

Here is some demo and example if you have user array then you have to clear user object first after push in userArray as

```
$scope. user = {};
```

Here is the link [Jsfiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/nyjLm3uy/)

```
$scope.addItem = function(user) {
  $scope.userArray.push(user);
  $scope.user = {};
  $localStorage.data = $scope.userArray;
  $scope.userdata = $localStorage.data;
}
```